# ProgrammingError when uploading image

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.4

this is a simple code to upload a image and im   getting this type of error

```
         from django.db import models
         from PIL import Image
          class Products(models.Model):
          name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
          slug = models.SlugField()
          description = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
          image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_photo',blank=True,null=True)


           def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name
         error :
              ProgrammingError at /admin/DESigning/products/add/
              column "image" of relation "DESigning_products" does not exist
              LINE 1: ...Signing_products" ("name", "slug", "description", "image") V..
```

Comment: Hey, looks like you haven't ran `syncdb`. Try deleting your old database and run it again.

Comment: it's not working same error

Answer (score 1):

You may need to start a new Djano app, 'python manage.py startapp appName',  and create the models.py in the new appName folder.  Then try makemigrations and migrate. If you don't have a specified django app your 'relation _____  does not exist'.  This can be found at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/